# Class C implements interface B which extends interface A, can you say C implements A?

Tags: java, inheritance

In case class C implements interface B and interface B extends interface A. Is it correct to say that class C implements interface A?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. C can override the methods of A.

Example: (It's not a good example, but it's just to show that C/Chimpanzee can override the methods of A/Animal)

```
interface Animal
{
    void giveBirth();
}

interface Mammal extends Animal
{
    void walk();
}

class Chimpanzee implements Mammal
{

    @Override
    public void giveBirth()
    {
        System.out.println("Chimpanzee gives birth.");
    }

    @Override
    public void walk()
    {
        System.out.println("Chimpanzee walks.");

    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think "override" is the right word here, since the methods of A have not been implemented yet. I would say "must implement".

Comment: You might add an example or two to illustrate. For example, Cat class implements Mammal interface which extends Animal interface, so, yes, a Cat object is an Animal. In the Java Collections framework, the TreeSet class implements the SortedSet interface which extends the Set interface, so, yes, a TreeSet object is a Set.

Comment: @vefthym I think either is fine. When you implement an interface method, you can use the `@Override` annotation.

Comment: @BasilBourque I just added an example. It's probably not the best example though. Haha.

Comment: that's true, I was mostly referring to the original meaning of the term. Nice example :)

Answer (score 1):

Even if I agree with the accepted answer with respect to the first part ("Yes."), I don't agree with the second part "C **can override** the methods of A".

I believe the correct description is that C **must implement** the methods of both A and B.

For example, if interface A declares the method fooA() and B declares the method fooB(), then C must implement both fooA() and fooB(). In that sense, yes, you can say that C implements interface A (since it implements an interface that extends A).

Comment: My main point of the question was mostly if it is allowed to say C implements A considering that in class C would be written only "implements B". Thank you.

Comment: sure, and to that I agree with the accepted answer. I just wanted to give a more accurate answer, as I see it.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer is correct. Because of polymorphism in the Java language, this is possible. **However**, one must understand the performance impact of using the JVM instruction `invokeDynamic` instead of `invokeVirtual`. The latter on requires a simple lookup in the class’s virtual table, whereas the former requires a much more in-depth recursive search through all of its implementor’s virtual method tables.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can say C implements A. The instanceof operator comes very handy here:

```
public interface B extends A {      
    public void b();    
}

public interface A {
    public void a();        
}    

public class C implements B {

@Override
public void a() {}

@Override
public void b() {}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    C c = new C();
    System.out.println("C is A? " + (c instanceof A));
    System.out.println("C is B? " + (c instanceof B));
}
```

}

The result will be:

```
C is A? true
C is B? true
```